# WordPress shortcode display as plain text

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a custom templates and I used custom shortcodes to displayed it in the page. But the shortcode is not working, its displayed as plain text only. I already deactivate and reactive the plugins but still have same issue.

I'm using this [info_box_calculator] but it display as plain text or sometimes it gives me a blank page

How to fix this?

```
function info_box_calculator(){
ob_start();
get_template_part('page-calcu-info-box');
return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('info_box_calculator', 'info_box_calculator');
```

[Link](http://www.homecredit.ph/4537-2/6367-2/)

Comment: The theme contains a file called `page-calcu-info-box.php`?  The blank page probably indicates a fatal PHP error which should appear in the server's error_log file.

Comment: Yes, I have that file. I check the error_log but i didn't find any error :(

Comment: What if you modify the shortcode function to return a string, like `return "THIS IS A TEST";`  Does that appear on your page?  I checked the link and I don't see the shortcode tag appearing, but not sure the correct output for it is there either.

Comment: No, it's not :( I try to display my existing custom shortcode and it displayed. But not that shortcode

Comment: Where exactly is the code you posted?  In a plugin you said?

Comment: No, that is my custom page template only

Comment: Try moving that code to the theme's functions.php file.  It should work then.

Comment: But my codes are too long to move in functions.php

Comment: If the add_shortcode or other hook functions are not in a plugin, or functions.php, then they wont' work since the relevant code isn't loaded soon enough.  You can put that in another file and `require_once` it in functions.php

Comment: the add_shortcode is place in functions.php

Comment: Your code above looks to be correct, so it's not that. It could be a plugin conflict? Have you tried with __all__ plugins disabled?

Comment: Do not mind. Your are sure to writing this shortcode in text mode? I mean you must be change text editor mode to  text mode from visual mode